# Dataframe to nested list with custom named vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and need to structure it into a list, where the column names are at the top-most level, followed by arbitrarily named vector of the column values, like so:

**Dataframe:**

```
tibble::tibble(col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
               col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 b         2
#> 3 c         3
#> 4 d         4
```

**Desired list:**

```
list(col1 = list(values = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), 
     col2 = list(values = c(1, 2, 3, 4)))
#> $col1
#> $col1$values
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
#> 
#> 
#> $col2
#> $col2$values
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
```

In the example above, the values of each of the columns are nested under the column names as a vector named "values".

Comment: `lapply(my_tibble, \(x) list(values = x))`

Comment: Thanks! I was certainly overthinking it. If you turn this into an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Given your response, the tidyverse version would be `purrr::map(my_tibble, ~list(values = .x))`.